# Google Cloud Platform IAM, i don't receive the invitation mail as a member

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

my partner added me as a member in a GCP project, with computer engine Admin role, but i didn't receive any invitation email.
we have already checked in spam folder.
i tried also to acc

https://console.cloud.google.com/invitation?project=PROJECT_NAME&account=EMAIL&memberEmail=EMAIL

but it given me this error:

[image]

Comment: I tested it on my end and I am experiencing the same issue. When granting a role to a user, the user will not receive an invitation email, unless he is granted a “Project Owner” role.

I will file an internal investigation. A Cloud IAM support person will look at the issue.

I understand that you need to monitor the progress of this investigation therefore the issue is made public. You may monitor the progress by visiting the [link in the Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/111843590). You may also add your feedback and information in the thread.

Answer (score 56):

Search with the search bar for the invitation on your email but if you don't find it access the following link:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/invitation?project=[your-project-id]&account=[the-account-email-invited]&memberEmail=[the-account-email-invited]
```

Comment: I'm astounded by how effortlessly this worked

Comment: Spent so much time trying to figure out wtf was wrong, and this "just worked".  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Thanks so much you saved my day. GCP's documentation team should learn from you.

Comment: The aged-old **JustWorks™** comes to mind... Thanks much @allan-veloso (I hope I didn't jinx it! )

Answer (score 11):

A workaround can be add as owner than change permission. (Not tested)

In my case the project was hidden under `No organization` > `All`.

Comment: Assigning `Owner` permission helped. _Pending invitation_ sign immediately appears next to Principal name.

Comment: This seems to be the ONLY way...

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on my end and I am experiencing the same issue. When granting a role to a user, the user will not receive an invitation email, unless he is granted a “Project Owner” role.

However, upon reading the GCP documentation [1], I do see that it's working as intended.

"To allow team members to access a project's resources and APIs, project owners can grant IAM roles to users. You can grant a role to a user using the GCP Console, the gcloud command-line tool, or the setIamPolicy() method. When you set a policy or add a binding to grant a role to a user, they won't receive an invite email. Instead, the user's access is updated directly." [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access